# Make edits to multiple xlsx files in diffierent directories

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am new to python so please excuse me if my wording is off. In my export folder I have other folders that each contain many xlsx files. I am trying to use openpyxl to loop through all the subfolders and add formulas to each xlsx in the directory. Here is my code so far but I am getting an error when trying to call the sheet name and also an error about not being able to parse headers.

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

directoryPath = r'c:\q3'
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename = os.path.join(folders, name)
            wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sensor Status")
            sheet['I3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,"=0")'
            sheet['I4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,">=0")'
            sheet['K3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",D:D,"=0")'
            sheet['K4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",D:D,">=0")'
            sheet['M3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",E:E,"=0")'
            sheet['M4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",E:E,">=0")'
            wb.save('filename')
```

Comment: What do the errors say? What lines are they from?

Comment: Please include the complete traceback. Also, does the error happen with every file? Or with just some?

Comment: If by traceback you mean the path: c:\users\username\documents\reporting\export\q3
The first error I get is Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored. There is no line associated with this error. 
The second error is: KeyError ("Worksheet {0} does not exist. ".format(key))

Comment: Okay so I found out that one of the excel files did not have that Worksheet name, now the issue I am having is that the scrip only get's applied to 1 excel file in a folder that contains 14 and is saving it to a new excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

directoryPath = r'c:\users\wpauling\documents\reporting\export\q3'
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename = os.path.join(folders, name)
            wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sensor Status")
            sheet['I3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,"=0")'
            sheet['I4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,">=0")'
            sheet['K3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",D:D,"=0")'
            sheet['K4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",D:D,">=0")'
            sheet['M3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",E:E,"=0")'
            sheet['M4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",E:E,">=0")'
            wb.save(filename)
```